# Using UNION ALL with the same conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, union, union-all

I have 22 tables where each has many columns. I want to select 10 columns conditioning on 4 column values using WHERE. For this, I have to repeat these 4 conditions and 10 columns for all 22 tables, which is inconvenient. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Nope. You write a really big sql statement with lots of copy/paste. Perhaps, if possible, consider fixing your schema because it seems odd you would have 22 very similar tables.

Comment: Uh, I was really hoping to skip the copy/paste thing. Unfortunately I'm retrieving the data from a database and this is how they structured it. Thanks. @JNevill

Comment: That's SQL for you. Often times when I'm stuck with this type of work, I write SQL to write the script. Like load the table names into a temp table and do something like `SELECT 'UNION ALL SELECT list, of, similar, columns FROM ' + temptable.tablename + ' ' as sqlstatement FROM temptable;` And then just copy and paste that beast back into your client and run.

Comment: Remember SQL is a special purpose, declarative language. But you can use any general purpose language (Java, Python, PHP, etc.)  to dynamically build your query and even connect to DB and run it. Also, 22 tables of same structure raises database design questions. Be sure to follow normalization principles. Suffixed and prefixed tables should be avoided.

Comment: A database design like this one smells. Why do you have 22 *similar* tables? Do they represent similar entities? If you want to handle them together they are probably related.

Answer (score 0):

If the 22 tables have the same structure and the conditions on 4 columns are equal or similar, you can union tables in a subquery and put only one where externally.

Example:

```
select x.*
from
    (
    select col1, col2, col3, col4
    from tab1
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3, col4
    from tab2
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3, col4
    from tab3
    ) x
where x.col1 = 'value' 
  and x.col2 = 'other value'
```